# Using VisualStudio's icons

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mef, intellisense

I'm writing an IntelliSense implementation and I'm trying to get access to VisualStudio's icon set. I understand you're meant to use MEF and somehow the property/field you import should be automatically populated. Currently I have:

```
[Import]
public IGlyphService GlyphService { get; set; }
```

GlyphService is always null. What am I missing?

- [Msdn Reference IGlyphService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.iglyphservice.aspx)
- [Msdn Reference Babel Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166402%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Have you looked at this [MSDN Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/roslyn/thread/325e18f5-857e-4cd1-8005-ce18ff94b846)

Comment: I tried that, it didn't seem to work. Is something specific required to get MEF to work?

Comment: which object returns GlyphService object? How was that object created?

Comment: Well my understanding is that MEF somehow populates it when the [Import] attribute is applied...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you do indeed have to manually populate and compose a CompositionContainer. My solution looks something like this:

```
// An aggregate catalog that combines multiple catalogs
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

// Adds all the parts found in the necessary assemblies
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(IGlyphService).Assembly));
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(SmartTagSurface).Assembly));

// Create the CompositionContainer with the parts in the catalog
CompositionContainer mefContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

// Fill the imports of this object
mefContainer.ComposeParts(this);
```

After running this the current object (or the one you have selected in compose parts) will have it's Imports populated. I ran into a couple of issues with this, including needing to have the referenced dll's in the program's bin folder.

Comment: Having the same problem as OP, I just tried this code but I'm getting a `ChangeRejectedException` at `mefContainer.ComposeParts(this);`, do you have an idea?